# Vanishing of real valued functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f(x), g(x)$  are real valued functions  and $f(x)+e^{i\theta} g(x)=0$ for all real $x$.  I want to know for what values of $\theta$,  $f(x)=0$, and $ g(x)=0$ for all real real $x?$  My observation is, it is true for all $0<\theta<2\pi$  except at $\theta=\pi$.  Am I correct?

Comment: Your first sentence needs rewriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true iff $e^{i\theta}$ is not a real number which is true iff $\theta \neq n\pi$ for any integer $n$. Your answer for $0<\theta<2\pi$ is correct but there is no reason why you should put this restriction.

Comment: Since the result is true on the real line, I think it is true for complex functions having isolated zeros $f(z)$ and $g(z)$, as well. Am I right?

Comment: @user159888 For complex functions this is not trur for any value of $\theta$. You can always start with  $G$ and define $f$ as $e^{-\theta) g$.

Comment: If I restrict $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ as polynomials, I think then it is true.

Comment: No, if $g$ is a polynomial so is $e^{-i\theta} g$.

Comment: Sorry I missed out mentioning polynomials with real coefficients.

Comment: Now you are back to the real case.